# Which analog input design is better?

Tags: analog, filter, input

We are designing analog input with RC low-pass filter and we want to be able to disconnect the filter if needed. So we came up with these two options. 1st option has jumper at the right side and has twice as much inputs because you literally have to disconnect the wire of the input and connect it for example from **IN1** to **IN2**.

[image]

The second design has only one input **IN** but we are concerned that if op-amp is used the wire above it might bring a lot of disturbances from the air... Also we are concerned about current which might flow in the op-amp output or (-).

[image]

Well what do you think?

Comment: In the 2nd case you run straight into the cap. Better find a way to make that filter active and bypass the cap, which will make you filter drop an order.

Comment: What is the reason to _not_ connect together in1 and in2 in your first schematics?

Comment: @Martin Oh Jesus... Thats right! Hahaha

Comment: Should we also put zenner on pin 2 of the jumper in our first design? Might be good right?

Comment: If you follow @Martin 's recommendation (which I second), adding a second zener is unnecessary. Whatever the jumper position, the input signal will be clamped by the zener.

Comment: Not to add the second one. To put existing one in front of an op-amp to protect it as well.

Comment: "1st option has jumper at the right side and has twice as much inputs because you literally have to disconnect the wire of the input and connect it for example from IN1 to IN2.", so you have the jumper in the picture and another jumper off screen to the left? I don't follow your description...

Comment: @71GA  If the application can tolerate the loading of C? and 100k, then U? is not needed and can be omitted

Comment: OUT goes directly into MCU's internal ADC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1st option has jumper at the right side and has twice as much inputs
>   because you literally have to disconnect the wire of the input and
>   connect it for example from IN1 to IN2

Is there any reason why you shouldn't do this: -

[image]

Comment: what is the purpose of having the zener diode in the circuit?

Comment: @drtechno there may be a purpose but realistically it is the OP who made this decision. On the face of it, it looks like it might be some over-voltage protection incase IN1 got too high. Now it works also to protect the op-amp for the same reason.

Comment: It is an over voltage protection. If input current exceeds 3.3V zenner opens up and redirects current into GND.

Comment: It does not assure a low (AC) impedance to the uP's ADC circuit, at J1-2, which many need (though I don't know Z of IN1). Nor does OP's of course

Comment: What would be your ideal circuit @HenryCrun

Comment: Really we need to know what is Zin and what is required by ADC. I was observing that if uP is AVR, and Zin is 100k, direct connection will not be adequate

Comment: then insead of one zener,  you would want an ac clipper (two zeners in series with the cathodes tied together) ? because its an audio circuit (AC signal) and not a servo circuit (dc control voltage).

Comment: The most negative supply to the opamp is 0 volts so no, I disagree @drtechno

Comment: isn't the signal ac? instead of dc? or is it an ac signal that is dc offset 1/2 of the zener voltage.

Comment: Ask the designer!!

Comment: because it would be asymetric  because the signal swing the forward bias direction would clamp the signal at the junction voltage (0.6v or so).

Answer (score 1):

What!!! Are you people made of jumper pins?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5qGpcm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This also provides a buffered input to the ADC for both settings.

Many uP on chip ADC require low AC Z (PIC, AVR) (e.g. 10k or XpF)

Further the uP is protected by U? in both settings.

Comment: What are you trying to say? Are we missing anything? This design looks super simple!

Comment: @71GA 2 pins is fewer than 3 pins. Oh, and it should be better as well as cheaper. 3 legs good, 2 legs better.  Don't call me Muntz

Comment: @71GA the first sentence of your question... you want to be able to disable the filter when needed. Well, this circuit might help because it acts as a buffer if SW2 is open. Or provides a filtered output when SW2 is closed. The possible disadvantage of this circuit is having a relatively high output impedance. I would use an active filter instead.

Comment: @RohatKılıç What's your simplest non inverting active filter?

Comment: Why does it matter to have only 2 pins?

I have a product where we have to use a number of 3 pin jumpers. These are 70% of first pass test failures. Most of these (50% of first pass fails) are "jumper on wrong pair" assembly faults. 2pin jumpers lack this fault mode. Originally, 3 pin jumpers accounted for ~$0.70 of $25. After ATE and manufacturing process improvements, 3pin ness now accounts for ~$0.15 of $15. That is still 3% of profit, but what can you do eh?

Comment: @Henry well, putting the opamp buffer after RC maybe (with keeping the switch, of course). Depending on the signal source's output impedance, we may require one more buffer so that the signal level is not decreased by dividing. I dont know the target's input impedance , but if it's in a few hundreds of kOhms or in MOhms range then the circuit above is well suitable.